# Weird ClassNotFoundException on Android during runtime

Tags: android, eclipse, runtime, classnotfoundexception

**Environment:**

- Mac OSX
- Eclipse Kelper
- Android 4.1 - 4.3

**Scenario:**

- Two projects (A & B)
- Project A is setup as "Library Project"
- Project B is setup to use Project as its sole library

  - This means that a jar file is automatically created under the 'Android Dependencies' folder
- During compile time, everything looks good (no error)
- However, during time time, I received a ClassNotFoundError for a class that is embedded in Class A

**Additional info:**
   I have to use A as B's library, because I am referring to a string in Project A's strings.xml from Project B.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, I ended up solving this one by exporting the project to a jar file...keep in mind that the jar file needs to be copied to the /lib in the project that consumes the library from the jar.